# Kotlin updating different values with a single function

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, code-reuse

I am making an app that will have multiple basic number trackers (the numbers are saved in a database),
Each tracker will have a button to add or reduce the number.

Is there a way to write a function in the viewmodel for adding or reducing the number that is reusable across all of the trackers?

Example code:

```
@Composable
fun TrackerScreen(viewModel: TrackerViewModel) {

    val trackerUiState = viewModel.TrackerUiState.collectAsState()

    Column{
        Text("${trackerUiState.value.Tracker.valueOne}"
        Row{
            Button(onClick = { //function to increase valueOne by One })
                { Text("+1") }
            Button(onClick = { //function to reduce valueOne by One })

    Column{
        Text("${trackerUiState.value.tracker.valueTwo}"
        Row{
            Button(onClick = { //function to increase valueTwo by One })
                { Text("+1") }
            Button(onClick = { //function to reduce valueTwo by One })
// etc...
```

The viewmodel calls the state of the database with a dataclass (tracker) for each field

```
data class TrackerDetails(
    val tracker: Tracker = Tracker()
)

data class Tracker(
    val valueOne: Int = 0,
    val valueTwo: Int = 0,
    //etc...
)
```

I know I can set these all up as individual functions:

```
fun increaseTrackerOneByOne() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val trackerUpdate = trackerUiState.value.tracker.toTracker()
        trackerRepository.updateTracker(trackerUpdate.copy(valueOne = trackerUpdate.valueOne + 1))
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to set up this kind of function to work regardless of the tracker it's attached to?

(The app I'm working on will have roughly 20-30 of these trackers, if not more, so it would save me a lot of space and typing as well as following best practice of not repeating code..)

Comment: No, there isn’t. Is Tracker a DAO? Why are all these similar things in different properties of a class instead of it being just a List or Map of Ints? That would be the way to avoid duplicated code. For example you could be creating all those columns of Composables in a loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Yes it's a DAO, from following the Inventory codelab but with some tweaks. The tracker is just a smaller part of a larger spread of Ints and Strings - only using one database as each entry will only ever have one value for each column.

Comment: The `trackerUiState` is a Stateflow of the data if that helps (I think that's a map already?) I'm very new to all this, so won't be surprised if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: If you have only one entry per column, you only have one row in your database. If all the columns are Ints, I think you should flip your database around to be one column and many rows. Then you can retrieve your stuff as a List. A flow of data is not a map in any way. It’s a flow of your data as the database changes. So when you start collecting it will emit your Examples class. Then when you modify the database, it will emit it again with the new changes.

Comment: Only one column won't work - what I'm creating is an interactive character sheet for a roleplaying game, so each row in the database is a character with a single value for every field (health points, mana points, stat values, etc.)
All of these values need to be raised and lowered by increments of one (for the most part) so I was hoping to shortcut the code to do that lol

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for now where I have:

- a mutableIntState number "editableNumber"
- a where function that calls a different edit line based on editableNumber.
- Each button sets the editableNumber to the line it wants to call.

This still requires a separate function line for each button and a composable for each button rather than being able to create them based off a list.forEach, but it's a start.